# Property 'then' does not exist on type '() => Promise<{}>'. - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Method**

```
  hola() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if(true) {
            resolve(true)
          }
        })
    }
```

**Calling the method**

```
this.hola.then(data => console.log(data));
```

**Error**

> Property 'then' does not exist on type '() => Promise<{}>'.

I already tried to restart ionic serve but it keeps throwing that error

Comment: Try calling the function: `this.hola().then(...)` (with the parentheses).

Comment: Ops! thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 29):

The parenthesis is missing while you are calling the method hola.

```js
this.hola().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call the method, try this instead, storring it in a variable of type "any" makes it ignore the "existence" of the proprety

```
    var a:any = this.slides.getActiveIndex()
    a.then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```